# Multiple task panes in Outlook add-in or how to open task pane with additional parameters

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am working on an Outlook add-in with React task pane. I'm trying to implement a button which would open a window where I'd have an input field and a button with onClick event. The thing is I already have two add-in buttons - one which opens the task pane and another one that simply executes a function.
My question is can I create a third button and when I click it it will open a different task pane or something else where I'd type a text and when I click the button next to that input field the text will be inserted in my mail.

I tried with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.contoso.com/myDialog.html', {height: 30, width: 20, displayInIframe: true}) but for some reason it is not loading the iframe with the html and so I can't test if this would work for me.

Comment: can't you do it within your side panel which is opened from 1st button?

Comment: @KishanVaishnani this would not work because I need a different menu.

Comment: Ok so, you need to create a new button as suggested in the comment below by Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT's

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your add-in is based off this repo (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-React), you can add more buttons to show up next to the two that you already have.

You have to modify the manifest XML file (manifest.outlook.xml) to include the new button:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
        <Group id="msgReadGroup">
            <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- New button starts here -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton1">
                <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label1" />
                <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label1" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip1" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon1.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon1.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon1.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url1" />
                </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- New button ends here -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                </Action>
            </Control>
        </Group>
    </OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Then, add resources for the new button:

```
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
    <!-- New image resources start here -->
    <bt:Image id="Icon1.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon1-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon1.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon1-32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon1.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon1-80.png"/>
    <!-- New image resources end here -->
  </bt:Images>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
    <!-- New URL resources start here -->
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url1" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane1.html" />
    <!-- New URL resources end here -->
  </bt:Urls>
  <bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
    <!-- New ShortString resources start here -->
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label1" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane1"/>
    <!-- New ShortString resources end here -->
    <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:LongStrings>
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
    <!-- New LongString resources start here -->
    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip1" DefaultValue="Opens a new pane to do new things."/>
    <!-- New LongString resources end here -->
    <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
  </bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
```

Note: You can use the same taskpane URL for both buttons/controls and just append different query parameters. Then the taskpane will change its UI/logic based on the query parameters that were passed in.

To insert some text into the body of the email when a button is clicked in the taskpane, you can use `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync` or `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync`. The former will replace everything in the body of the email, whereas the latter will add to it.

Full documentation about these APIs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview